# why would two radios in the same group have different size check dots?

Tags: html

This might be common knowledge, but I couldn't find it...  Sometimes, two radios styled exactly the same will have different size checked indicators, the black dot will be bigger in one than the other.  Why is that?  And how do you fix it?

Here are two screen shots of the same radio group:

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the html.  I removed style just in case that was causing it, but I still get it.

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><td>New or Maintenance</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="rNewOrMaint" id="rNewOrMaint" value="New"/> New
        <input type="radio" name="rNewOrMaint" id="rNewOrMaint" value="Maintenance"/> Maintenance</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I just tried this in Firefox, Chrome and IE11. Works fine in all of those.

Comment: Hey Mike, is there any chance that an external style is making a) one of the radio buttons bigger or b) one of the font sizes bigger?

Comment: Can we see the CSS behind these elements too?

Comment: @Mike Ok, IE8, so if no styles affect the inputs, IE8 user agent stylesheet presumably uses a different style for radio: selected / focus.

Comment: I just tried commenting out everything but meta and title in the head and get the same thing.

Comment: What's weird too, on the same page, there are a seperate group of radios it doesn't happen on.

Comment: If I add a <br /> between, it goes away, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Things are changed now(not relevant post according to today's standards).

But consider to.

1- Change *Styling where CSS is present.* (external-file, inline, same file)